# Can I configure SpringBoot app to run on a tomcat that is added to eclipse IDE in its servers tab?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create a spring boot web app. But i dont want to create a jar out of it.
I want to run the web app directly from eclipse on to the tomcat that is added to eclipse via servers tab.

Is it possible? How to achieve it?

Comment: You might want to read [this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/03/07/deploying-spring-boot-applications#what-about-the-java-ee-application-server)

Comment: this is from the reference documentation of spring-boot 2.0 release https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file